# subprocess.Popen doesn't run the bash command?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, subprocess

I have tried using subprocess .Popen in Python IDLE, in both versions 2.7 and 3.2 and the code didn't work!!!

[image: The Python Code]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain that the commands aren't being run and you're just not seeing the output in the IDLE terminal? Try running 'touch /tmp/testfile' this way and see if /tmp/testfile is created.

Comment: just a guess: the shell is closed, when the code is executed, so you dont see any result; try to add a wait, pause, if you just wnat to check if this is working...

Comment: No, there is no result when the shell is closed or open

Comment: What does `==== No Subprocess ====` mean? And why didn't you just put the displayed stuff into your question instead of a screenshot of the window?

Comment: I didn't type ===No Subprocess=== it appears every time I use IDLE

Comment: @PeterEzzat That's clear. But as I am not familiar with IDLE, I wonder what it might mean. Maybe it refers to that what you see here...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that IDLE redirects Python's `stdout` so that `print`ing happens in the window, but it doesn't redirect file descriptor 1, so that any subprocess happily prints to that file descriptor.

Try to start IDLE from the command line, run these lines and see if their output is printed to the terminal where IDLE is called from.

Solutions:

1. Don't use IDLE. Call your stuff from a `python` interpreter called from the command line.
2. Redirect the output of your processes to a pipe, read this pipe and output it. Such as:

   ```
   sp = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   for i in sp.stdout: print i
   sp.wait()
   ```

Comment: it worked, but how can i use it in IDLE?<br /> This even Worked, in terminal too:<br />import subprocess<br />
subprocess.Popen('echo "Hello World"', shell=True)

Comment: Solution 2 (pipe and `for` loop) should work in IDLE as well. Besides, you only should use `shell=True` if absolutely necessary. Better use `subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello World'])` resp. `sp = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello World'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.